# Why cache entire POJO if we only need to cache a particular object

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

In this link: http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/UsingCacheable
they say:

```
When the above POJO is defined as a bean in a Spring IoC container, the bean instance can be made 'cacheable' by adding merely one line of XML configuration.
```

Without using a caching framework, I would just declare Weather and List as static and that would have taken care of caching.

So my question is that if I want to just have the `Weather`  and `List<Location>` to be cached, then why would I cache the entire DAO?
Also behind the scenes, does the annotation `@Cacheable` turn `Weather` and `List<Location>` into static variables?

Comment: "*Weather and List as static*" - these are classes, do you mean `*`getWeather()` and `findLocations()` static*". Also how do you think making anything `static` can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code in question:

```
public interface WeatherDao {

    public Weather getWeather(String zipCode);

    public List<Location> findLocations(String locationSearch);
}

public class DefaultWeatherDao implements WeatherDao {

    @Cacheable(cacheName="weatherCache")
    public Weather getWeather(String zipCode) {
        //Some Code
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheName="locationSearchCache")
    public List<Location> findLocations(String locationSearch) {
        //Some Code
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand your points about `static` variables. In essence there is a *map* from `zipCode` to `Weather` and similar from `locationSearch` to `List<Location>`. This map can come from a database, file, external API, etc.

Do you want to create a map with all possible arguments as keys and corresponding values? Sure, you can, but it has several drawbacks:

- you put a lot of pressure on your heap. In many cases the amount of data might never fit into memory, or even on your disk (think: caching Google search engine by storing every possible search query and list of hits)
- most likely you won't use most of the keys, ever. Why store them in memory?
- what about eviction? I bet these methods tend to return different weather for the same ZIP code over the time...

Since I don't fully understand your arguments, let me explain briefly what happens behind the scenes when `getWeather()` is called:

- transparent proxy intercepts `getWeather()` call and looks up `weatherCache`
- in that cache it uses `zipCode` argument as cache key
- if such entry exists (of type `Weather`) it is returned immediately
- if the above is not the case, control is delegated to the real `getWeather()` method. It can call some API, run database query or do some lengthy computations
- the result of `getWeather()` is placed in the `weatherCache` for future reference.

No `static` is involved here.

---

BTW [Spring 3.1 introduced caching abstraction layer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) that probably makes this Google Code project obsolete. It looks the same and allows seamless integration with different cache implementations.

Comment: Thank you. But why I need to cache the whole DAO? I just need to cahce the Map(s)

Comment: @Kaushik: I don't understand what you mean by "*caching whole DAO*". You are caching each method separately in separate "maps"

Comment: When they say:the bean instance can be made 'cacheable' ...what is the bean instance? The 'Weather' bean?